# Class property default value if not assigned

Tags: c#, class, properties, null, default-value

I'm having a dilemma what the best approach is to the following problem:

```
public class Address
{
    public Address() { }

    public Address(string street) 
    {
        Street = street;
    }

    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

The above code will create an Address with only a Street `property` (for this example). Because a `string` is a reference type it is `null` by default. Because the Street `property` will be null by default, the user of this Address `class` would have to check if the `property` Street is null or not before doing something with it what might throw an exception.

My question now is, it it better to

1. Leave all `properties` in a `class` with the default value like `string = null`, `int = 0`, ...?
2. Give each `property` a value? This concerns `strings` not being `null` but rather `string.Empty`.

What is the general approach to this problem? I tried to find some information about this on the web but I don't know the good search words to describe what I actually want to find out. The main question comes down to this: **Is it better to give all `properties` in a `class` a `null` value if they are not assigned or better to leave them with their `default` value?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructors should always leave your object in a valid state. The only *legitimate* reason to leave a property unassigned past the constructor is that the property is optional according to your design. If a constructor leaves a required property unassigned, the object would be in an invalid state, so the constructor should be fixed.

The answer to your question is "it depends on your design":

- If a property is optional, leave it `null`.
- If a property is required and you have a suitable default value for it, assign the default value to the property
- If a property is required and you have no suitable default value, make sure that all constructors assign the required property.

For a single-property class like yours it hardly makes sense to leave `Street` unassigned, so I would re-evaluate the design reasons for introducing the default constructor in the first place.